# IPAddress.GetAddressBytes() method - what byte order?

Tags: c#, ip-address

What is the byte ordering of the 4-byte array returned by the `GetAddressBytes()` method of `IPAddress` class?

[More on the GetAddressBytes method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.getaddressbytes.aspx).

Is it big or little endian? I need to put some IP addresses to the message body, so it is important to me.

Answer (score 13):

Network byte order ( = big endian). See:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_in_networking
- http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Byte-Order.html

Comment: This is correct according to my tests. But it would be nice if there was an official doc to confirm, or at least a .NET framework source code sample.

Comment: @JordanRieger: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/IPAddress.cs,004b582eb374555f

Answer (score 6):

Big-Endian: `127.0.0.1` -> [127, 0, 0, 1]

Answer (score 5):

The same as the address you would read it if you had it as a normal dotted string.

Ie. "127.0.0.1" will give you 127, 0, 0, 1, in that order.